# getting error on frequency distribution,TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, nltk

```
doc_clean = []
stopwords_corpus = UrduCorpusReader('./data', ['stopwords-ur.txt'])    
stopwords = stopwords_corpus.words()
# print(stopwords)
for infile in (wordlists.fileids()):
    words = wordlists.words(infile)
    print(infile)
    #print(words)
    finalized_words = remove_urdu_stopwords(stopwords, words)
    print("\n==== WITHOUT STOPWORDS ===========\n")
    print(finalized_words)
    doc_clean.append(finalized_words)
fdist1 = FreqDist(doc_clean) 
print(fdist1)
```

i am trying to calculate frequency of each word in a vocabulary.say i have 10 documents,firstly i have performed tokenization and then removed some stop words from these docs,i read about Frequency Distribution in nltk by using this i tried to count frequency of each item in these documents.but i am getting errorTypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you meant to build a list of all words (after cleanup), but this line appends *each list* as an element of `doc_clean`:

```
doc_clean.append(finalized_words)
```

Basically, `FreqDist` will count the different elements of your list-- so if these elements are lists, you've got a problem. To build a single list of the words from all documents, replace `append()` with `extend()`:

```
doc_clean.extend(finalized_words)
```

Comment: i have 15 files after cleanup i want to access the result of all files to gather thats why i used append

Comment: I'm sorry I've no idea what you are trying to say. Do you want to count frequencies for all data together, or for each file separately?

Comment: suppose i have files with name file1,file2,file3,file4...etc.firstly i loaded all files and then processed these files.now i want to calculate frequency of each word in all these files

Comment: Can you try to answer my question?

Comment: i tried it.it worked for freqdis.but then it wrote some thing like this after calculating frequency all_tokens = sum(doc_clean, []).it gives me errorTypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: I'll try one more time. **Do you want to count frequencies for all data together, or for each file separately?**

Comment: all data together.suppose i have a file with a word 'sports' and it appear in 7 files.i should count it collectively.

Comment: The code in my answer works -- as long as  `remove_urdu_stopwords()` returns a list of _words_ (like its argument). If you are still getting an error, try to debug it by leaving stopword removal out of the process.